# importing react component files outside of src in create-react-app give error Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (9:9)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, babeljs

i have create on react component using create-react-app
comp-a which have following dir strcuture

```
src
  comp-view.js
package.json
... etc
```

now am trying to import this file from another component 'comp-b'
comp-a is mentioned as a dependency in comp-b
package.json of comp-b

```
dependency: {
   comp-a: "^0.1.0"
}
```

am trying to do import in comp-b like below

```
import {comp} from 'comp-a/src/comp-view'
```

and now am getting error like  Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (9:9)

how this can be fixed

Comment: project created using create-react-app restricts you to import files outside src, you should move file inside src folder, if you can't do that then I think you've to eject and make changes in webpack config

Comment: am not importing the files outside src, am adding the other module as dependency and importing from that module

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding

`require("@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx").default`

in the `babel-preset-react-app/dependencies.js` file.